# LazyLoadImageModule on Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Hello i am upgrading my app from Ionic 3 to Ionic 5

I used to have LazyLoadImageModule to load multiple images. Now i am getting an error when i used it in html pages **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined**

This is how i use it.

home.module.ts

```
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image';
imports: [
  LazyLoadImageModule
],
```

home.ts

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
 defaultImage: string = 'assets/img/user.png';
```

home.html

```
<ion-content #container>
  <img [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="item.profile_pic" [scrollTarget]="container._scrollContent.nativeElement" />
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image';

 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    LazyLoadImageModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomePage
    }
   ])
   ],
   declarations: [HomePage]
  })
  export class HomePageModule {}
```

item array returns as wanted. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ngmodule section in your module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    HomePage,
],
imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
],
exports: [
    HomePage
]    
})
```

See also [here](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-3-lazy-loading-modules/)

Comment: Thanks Micha. app.module.ts? I use Ionic 5 you can't use ionic-angular

Comment: See Update above

Comment: the link you send me, its true it says about 5 but that applies only in Ionic 3.